# How to change the Ubuntu partition from sda to sdb

Tags: partitioning

I have a dual boot in my computer. Both Ubuntu and Windows partitions are in `/dev/sda`. There is not free space to use. I want to generate Ubuntu from `/dev/sda` into `/dev/sdb` because there is enough storage space in `/dev/sdb`. Can you give any recommendations?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you need more space in `/home` your easiest option, I think, is to move the `/home` partition to `dev/sdb2`. If it's the `/` partition that causes the space problems (we can't tell because none of the partitions is really full) then that won't work.

Comment: "Can you give any recommendation?" Any recommendation will be opinion based (different options are possible) and are very dependent on a specific setup. Therefore voting to close this question.

Comment: how to  move the /home partition to dev/sdb2?

Comment: To move data from one partition to another; I'd boot *live* media and copy the data across. Booting *live* media probably isn't necessary either.. but using *live* media ensures no file in the partition is in-use/changing etc.. but there are many ways to do it too.

Comment: Does this help? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving